# Huawei Y635-L01 Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rom-flashing, rom, huawei

Has anyone got a way to flash lollipop on the Huawei Y635? The guides on google aren't that help full.. 
Beat answers will get voted up
Thanks
FlashWaihi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only available via custom ROMs, which you'll need quite a bit of research before diving into. Consider using this [XDA-Developers thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/huawei-y635-development-t3294138) for a start.

Note: As it is for all Huawei phones, you need to apply for unlocking the bootloader first. Furthermore, the page points out that you will only get 3.1MP camera at best with any Lollipop custom ROM, and you need a special modem for calls to work correctly.